# Special case: Derivative of a vector with respect to another vector

Tags: calculus, matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I have that

$$ x = [a \ \ B]^{-1}c $$

where $x$, $a$, and $c$ are all $p \times 1$, and $B$ is $p \times (p-1)$, so that the invertible matrix $[a \ \ B]$ is $p \times p$.

I would like to compute the partial derivatives of the elements of $x$ with respect to the elements of $a$, which I believe can be expressed in a $p \times p$ matrix.

I have been working through the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). So far I have that the matrix of partial derivatives is something like

$$ [a \ \ B]^{-1} diag(c) [a \ \ B]^{-1} $$

where $diag(c)$ is the diagonal matrix whose main diagonal is $c$.

This matches my expectations in special cases, such as where $p=1$ and where $ [a \ \ B]$ is diagonal. But I am not sure it is right in general and I could use some help finding my way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the matrix $$G = [\,a\,\,B\,]$$ and rewrite the equation to clear the inverse, then find the differential, and then the gradient. 
$$\eqalign{
 c &= Gx \cr
 0 &= dG\,x + G\,dx \cr
dx
  &= -G^{-1}\,dG\,x \cr
  &= -G^{-1}\,[\,da\,\,0\,]\,x \cr
  &= -G^{-1}\,(x_1)\,da \cr
  &= -(x_1)G^{-1}\,da \cr
\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} &= -(x_1)G^{-1} &\implies 
\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial a_j} = -(x_1)\,e_i^TG^{-1}e_j \cr
}$$
This can be extended to columns beyond the first. 

Denoting the $k^{th}$ column of $G$ by $G_k$, an analogous derivation yields
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial x}{\partial G_k} = -(x_k)G^{-1}
 \,\,\,\implies 
\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial G_{jk}} = -(x_k)\,e_i^TG^{-1}e_j
}$$

Comment: Thanks $greg$. That's very helpful. The stickiest part for me is the substitution of  $[da \ 0]$ for $dG$. My instinct was that the derivative of $G$ with respect to $a$ has to be high-dimensional because it's the derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector. But I guess the point is that we are working with differentials, not derivatives. I also checked that in the $p=1$ case this matches my expectation, because then $G=a$ for $a$ a scalar, so $x=c/a$ and $dx/da = -c/a^2 = -x/a$.

Comment: Since $x_k=e_k^TG^{-1}c$ you could write the final expression as  $$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial G_{jk}} = -e_i^TG^{-1}e_je_k^TG^{-1}c$$

Comment: Yes, that form puts it closer to my attempt and makes it easier for me to see how the answer relates to the usual rule for the derivative of a matrix inverse.